# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" inside twig template when using json object as parameter

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a twig function which takes an array as a parameter, therefore I'm using it like this

`<a href="{{ { (group.id) : filter.value }|urlManipulate }}"`

However, for this line I'm getting the error `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Trying to get property of non-object")`

If I replace `group.id` with anything (e.g. `'test'`) it works without problems, so the `group` object is somehow the problem. However, when I add `{{ dump(group.id) }}` right above the `a` tag I'm getting output. So why do I have this bug? I already deleted the cache with `cache:clear`.

Just to clarify once more: `group` is a valid object. I can dump it. It has output. I can also dump `group.id`, but as soon as I want to use it as an array key, it doesn't work. What I tried is this

- `<a href="{{ { (group.id) : filter.value }|urlManipulate }}"`
- `<a href="{{ { group.id : filter.value }|urlManipulate }}"`
- `<a href="{{ { attribute(id, group) : filter.value }|urlManipulate }}"`

None of these worked. By the way: For another co-worker the first approach works without any problems. Only for me, this error is thrown.

Comment: Are you using this code in a loop and how do you get this *group* object?

Comment: Yes I am. `{% for group in groups %}`. Is your guess that one element inside the loop could be a non-valid object? If yes, then shouldn't be there also an error when dumping `group.id` in each iteration?

Comment: Yes, my guess is one of the items is not an object. Have you tried something like this inside the loop `if ( !is_object($group) ) { var_dump( $group ); die; }`.

Comment: But as I said: Shouldn't there be an error nonetheless because I'm dumping `group.id` ? I'm now duming `group` inside the iteration. No error, everything is an object.

Comment: Yes, you should get an error when dumping `group.id`. This is weird that you don't have it.

Comment: Yes, and I have absolutely no idea why.